# correct usage of pieces?

Tags: grammar

If I want to order more than one piece.
Do I say "3piece of something" or " 3pieces of something"?
I saw that some people use 'pieces' but some people didn't use it. Just used 'piece' without the plural. 
which one is correct ?

Comment: Can you give an example? As far as I know, _piece_ is a perfectly ordinary count noun, which always takes the plural with a number above 1.

Comment: They were wearing two-piece suits, and sitting on a three-piece suite, counting their pieces-of-eight.

Comment: I lost 3 pieces from my 1000-piece jigsaw puzzle.

Comment: If I order some food, like chicken wing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the context is:

> I bought **3 piece(s) of something**.

then "piece" is used in its most ordinary form. That is why it should be in plural form, to match "3".

---

However, there are special uses, where the rule is different:

> I bought a **2-piece** set
>
> I wear a **3-piece** suit.

Here, "piece" is not a stand-alone word, but a fragment of the expression **"N-piece (something)"**.